# how can I perform write operation of ble in android when continuous read operation is going on?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with ble in android. I can do the read and write operations successfully. I want to read continuously with a delay of 1 or 2 seconds.But when this continuous read operation is going on I cann't perform the write operation well. What will be a solution for it? My read function is

```
 @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,                                               //Read function
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic     characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
  if (BleUuid.UPDATE_TIME                        
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(characteristic.getUuid().toString()))     {
                name2 = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                      public void run() {

                        dose2.setText(String.valueOf(name2));


                    }
                });
try {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                 mConnGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);                  

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
               }



            }

        }
```

Comment: I have a number of switches in the ui performing the write operation. When this continuous read operation is going on I cann't do other operations

Comment: Can you correct your question and format your code?